# Change "Implement interface" template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I'm constantly using the "Implement interface" shortcut in Visual Studio 2008. My "problem" is that i want Visual Studio to use the *String*-alias instead of *string* in every instance.

Since i'm forced to use String instead of string this would save me a great ammount of time. For example, i want the following:

```
public Catalogue(String url) { }
```

instead of

```
public Catalogue(string url) { }
```

Is this possible? Where do I find these templates?

Comment: What happens if the interface you're implementing uses "String"?

Comment: That's what i'm using all the time. Visual Studio still gives me "string".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the templates used during refactorings.

Templates that you can change are available in *%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE*.  Specifically, most of the CSharp ones for blank files and such are in *%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp*

Maybe the person forcing you to use "String" would change their ways if they realized how much time this wasted.  I personally don't understand this...

The IDE uses "string", and not "String" in all generated code - so by forcing a non-standard "standard" your team is inviting inconsistency.  People can debate about which is better until they're blue in the face - but as you point out, **using "String" is a pain in the ass**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess I'll have to live with this.

Comment: Sorry :(  Check out third party refactoring tools like Resharper.  Maybe they behave different?

Answer (score 1):

just replace `string` with `String` (whole word, case sensitive) or don't use this factoring template. because after examination %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ it seems to be hardcoded